# FastAPI and SlowAPI not working on Ajax and getJSON request - python

Tags: python, jquery, xmlhttprequest, fastapi, slowapi

I'm having a problem. When I make too many requests from browser or postman rightly the API (slowapi) blocks me as I have correctly set, but if I make a request via AJAX and jquery's $ .getJSON, the APIs don't block me. How can I solve?
My code (extracted from the complete code):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, status
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from slowapi import Limiter, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler
from slowapi.util import get_remote_address
from slowapi.errors import RateLimitExceeded
from slowapi.middleware import SlowAPIMiddleware
limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address, default_limits=["2/5seconds"])
app = FastAPI()
app.state.limiter = limiter
app.add_exception_handler(RateLimitExceeded, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler)
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
app.add_middleware(SlowAPIMiddleware)

@app.get('/schools/{regione}/{provincia}/{comune}')
def search_school(request: Request, response: Response, regione: str, provincia: str, comune: str):
    if(request.headers.get("Provider") == "Test-User-Provider"):
        return {"message": "OK", "status": "success", "code": 200}

    else:
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        return {"message": "Provider not found", "status": "error", "code": 400}
```

Browser result (WORK):

```
{"error":"Rate limit exceeded: 2 per 5 second"}
```

Jquery code (NOT WORK):

```
$.getJSON(apiURL+"/schools/Test/Test/Test", function(data) {
        console.log(data)
});
```

Obviously with jquery I tried to make a lot of requests per second
Console browser result (Not limited!):

```
{message: '...', status: 'success', code: 200}
```

[image: Request not rate-limited]

A thousand thanks.

**UPDATE**
Through jquery I tried to make requests to other paths and it is correctly rate-limited. If I make the request to this path `/schools/{region}/{province}/{municipality}` the rate-limit does not work

**UPDATE 2**

I refer the updated and tested code. When I send a request to path `/testpath /{region}` it is correctly rate-limited. If instead I send a request to some sub-paths (`/schools/{region}/{province}/{municipality}` it is not rate-limited.

The jQuery code is the same as listed above

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, status
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from slowapi import Limiter, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler
from slowapi.util import get_remote_address
from slowapi.errors import RateLimitExceeded
from slowapi.middleware import SlowAPIMiddleware

limiter = Limiter(key_func=get_remote_address, default_limits=["2/5seconds"])
app = FastAPI()
app.state.limiter = limiter
app.add_exception_handler(RateLimitExceeded, _rate_limit_exceeded_handler)

origins = ["http://127.0.0.1/", "http://localhost", "http://192.168.1.75"] ## CORS

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
app.add_middleware(SlowAPIMiddleware) ## Rate-limit all request

@app.get('/schools/{regione}/{provincia}/{comune}')
def search_school(request: Request, response: Response, regione: str, provincia: str, comune: str):
        return {"message": 'No schools found!', "status": 'error', "code": 200} ## Or if found return schools informations

@app.get('/testpath/{regione}') ## Works with one path. If I add "provincia" and "comune" non work
def search_school(request: Request, response: Response, regione: str, provincia: str, comune: str):
        return {"message": 'No schools found!', "status": 'error', "code": 200} ## Or if found return schools informations
```

If i use schools path:
[image]

If i use testpath it's correct rate-limited:
[image]

Comment: The URL in your `getJSON` call doesn't match the URL path used in your example; have you actually limited the endpoint you're calling? Are you actually getting data _from the endpoint_ and not being terminated by a dependency?

Comment: no sorry, I wrote wrong now I correct it.  However all requests are limited with middleware

Comment: Since the `status` entry is error - are you sure your request even passes? Is your view function _actually_ invoked? (attach a debugger or do a print statement) - that something gets logged doesn't mean that it was actually invoked.

Comment: Everything works correctly the same request that the
I do it as a jquery or I do it as a browser, it returns what I want. the problem is with jquery that it is not rate limited which happens correctly with browser. In the console it prints me the requests I make and what I get back.

Comment: the status response is personalized and I decided it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your code and works fine, as long as you replace the closing double quote `”` with a straight double quote `"` in the `getJSON()` method:

```
$.getJSON(apiURL + "/security/validate_token", function(data) {
        console.log(data)
});
```

Above you wrote *"the status response is personalized and I decided it myself"*. So, if you still get a `{message: '...', status: 'success', code: 200}` response, I would suggest you try returning a simple message instead, e.g., `return {"status": "success"}`, and see if that works as expected. If not, it might be something not implemented in the right way in your custom response.

### Update

The below should work as expected. If it doesn't, then the issue likely lies elsewhere in code that is not inlcuded in your question. I would also suggest to add it as a [tempalte](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/) to your app, as from the error you posted you seem to be getting `Cross-Origin` warnings.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" >
         function on_click(){
            $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/schools/Test/Test/Test", function(data) {
                 console.log(data)
            });
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="on_click()">
   </body>
</html>
```